# Optimization model where a certain conditions affect objective rather than being a constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I have a minimization problem related to packing. I have to distribute a given amount of items from different sets to different packs. Each pack must be either empty or have a certain minimum of items. There is a penalty on each pack so i have to minimize the amount of packs

But there is also a **penalty** (rather than a constraint) for having items from different sets in the same packs so it is

$$\min  C_1 \sum_{i}^{packs}if(X_{i,any} >0 ) + C_2\sum_{j}^{packs}if[\exists 
X_{ij}>0,X_{kj}>0;k\neq i
 ]$$

when $x_{i,j }$ is number of items from $j$ in pack $i$. Also it's a constraint that $ \sum X_{i,j} = \text{constant}$

What model can I use to solve that problem?

---

**edit:**

My problem is that my objective function is not continuous, and as far as I found out is not good for any linear or non-linear programming solution.

is there a way to either replace it with a function that gives a similar solution to the problem or is there another way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your math is a little bit difficult to read. I can try to parse the first term. Let's introduce a binary variable $y_i$ indicating if bin $i$ is used. Then we can write:

$$\begin{align} \min\> & C_1 \sum_i y_i\\
                     &M_i y_i \ge x_{i,j} &\forall i,j \\
                     &y_{i} \in \{0,1\}
\end{align}$$

This is linear. $M_i$ is a large enough constant, to be chosen with care. I think this is what you want to achieve in the first part.

Sorry, I don't understand what you try to achieve in the second part.

In your text you indicate you want to model: "*Each pack must be either empty or have a certain minimum of items*." In other words: if $y_{i} = 1$ then $\sum_j x_{i,j}\ge L$. This can be modeled as:

$$\sum_j x_{i,j} \ge y_i L
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, you are correct and it helped me, what i am trying to do in the second part is some kind of variable that is true when more than one cell is not zero in a row (with the same j), a pack of items that come from mix of sets.

Comment: But X(i,j) variables are not binary, how can I create that step function to indicate when X(i,j) is non zero?

Comment: Indeed: see the $M_i$ in the first constraint. It is an upper bound on the number of items $j$ in bin $i$.